# ECS starting tasks sequentially though resources are available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In our ECS cluster setup with ASG Capacity provider, we have 5 EC2 instances and each instance can take around 20 tasks. So overall there are resources available to run 100 tasks. Now if we submit a service with 100 tasks, though there are enough resources, not all tasks are started parallely. I see tasks are coming up in batches of size 20 with a gap of 10 secs between each batch. I observed this from ECS Service Event logs. Any configuration which we can tweak to achieve complete parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to artificially controlled throughput (expressed in Tasks per Second - TPS) that the ECS service control plane imposes. There is a bursting concept in there (which is the reason for which you see this batch of tasks being launched and then a delta in seconds). The reasons for which these limits exist is to avoid being throttled in other parts of the services surface. These limits can be lifted if there is a strong need but the engineering team will need to validate the use case and expectations (see the point about hitting potentially other limits). The best way to address this discussion is by opening a ticket with AWS Support and explore your alternatives (based on your requirements).